# Facebook Post query deprecated

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was querying public posts using Facebook API with the following URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v1.0/search?q=XXX&type=post&access_token=XXX
```

And it was working fine. After that, I tried to use a recent account, and API keeps returning an error telling that this method is deprecated.

I can't find any other option to query public posts (feeds) using v2.0. Is there any?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public post search has been removed from v2.0. If you created your app after 4/30/2014 you can only use v2.0. Even if you specify v1.0 in the url v2.0 will be used.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @WizKid.. but you know any other query that let you do something like this? I can't find any reading the documentation.

Comment: I'm pretty confused... Because there are so many companies that do something like this... I found something here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/ ...is there any method that normal users can do using stream? If not, is there any way to register a company and continue doing this query?

Comment: Yes many companies are still using v1.0 but that will be deprecated in less then 1 year for them and they will have to use v2.0. In v2.0 you can only access data for users that are using your app

Comment: Hmm I get it.. that's sad... because there are companies that only do this oO (keeps monitoring social networks).. and this way, they won't be able to query facebook .. wow! =o